# Use a calculated total value in another table cognos report studio

Tags: report, cognos

I am trying to use a calculated total value from one cross tab in another cross tab with a different query. Alternatively I would like to put both queries in the same cross tab but use two different values for the row data values. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do query operations (joins, unions) to combine calculated fields from different queries.

You can write different calculations for cross-tab rows by pulling differently calculated data items in rows.

There are also lot's of calculated functions (running-totals, periodToDate) to calculate YTD, MTD values — that's the main reason for similar questions in my experience.

A simple example of what you're trying to achieve would help provide better / more detailed options.

Cheers